# How to single sort multiple queries by the same condition in sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to pull multiple sheets into one using the query function like so

```
={QUERY(Sheet2!A2:B, "SELECT A, B WHERE A <> ''");
  QUERY(Sheet3!A2:B, "SELECT A, B WHERE A <> ''")},...
```

doing this is fine but I would like the queries to be mixed in as to show a compiled list by the date in an ascending order any ideas on how to do this?

Also, I have tried to include sort by statements but it does not mix all the queries into one.

Comment: So what i ended up doing was, creating a new sheet, setting up a query using my original sheet, and then used the order by statement to sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is to wrap it into another `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY(
 {QUERY(Sheet2!A2:B, "SELECT A, B WHERE A <> ''");
  QUERY(Sheet3!A2:B, "SELECT A, B WHERE A <> ''")},
 "order by Col1")
```